# Automating a bulk copy/paste job

Tags: excel, vbscript, scripting

I want to automate a task as scripting the job is faster and would automate the task for future instances. I know Java so the logic is here (I think :X), but I am very lost as to the actual syntax and implementation for this script.

I have a collection of excel files called:

- Pc_Profile.xls
- Pc_Profile(n).xls
- Pc_Profile(n+1).xls

I have one master doc called:

- db.xls

Each pc profile doc has contents I need pasted into the master doc. Here are the contents:

A5:D5,
A8:B8,
A13:B13,
A15:D17,
A24:E26,
A28:B30,
A43:B43,
A45:B45

The contents of the cells listed above need to be separated into individual sheets, so the contents of each pc profile doc never reside in the same sheet within the master doc (db.xls). Each sheet needs to be renamed to the contents of cell A5 for each respective sheet.

Here is my pseudo-code:

```
set screen updating to false
set application updating to xlManual

//1st run:
open pc_profile.xls
copy desired contents to clipboard
open db.xls
paste clipboard to A1
Copy A5 to clipboard
Rename sheet > paste from clipboard

//second run (loop)
$number=1
Foreach file in directory
    open pc_profile($number).xls
    copy desired contents to clipboard
    open db_lukatsy.xls
    create new sheet
    set sheet as active
    paste clipboard to A1
    Copy A5 to clipboard
    Rename sheet > paste from clipboard
    $number++

object worksheets save changes
set screen updating to true
```

That was my thought process but feel free to re-structure if that is illogical. Basically my base case is the first pc profile. Then, I want to loop through all remaining instances of the collection and paste the contents into the db.xls, each within their own sheet, and renamed per cell A5.

This is what I have so far, although it's far from completion:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Set objworkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _ ("\\[directory]\Pc_Profile.xls")
objExcel.Visible = False

Dim target as Workbook
Set target = Application.Workbooks.Add

objWorkbook.Worksheets("Pc_Profile").Range("A5:D5").Copy

Set objworkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _ ("\\[directory]\db.xls")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set target = Application.Workbooks.Add
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 
objWorkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
ActiveSheet.Name = "A5"
```

Comment: Are you using VB.Net (in Visual Studio), VBA (in Excel) or VBScript (using Windows Scripting Host)? You have tagged your question with all three, but they are each different.

Comment: Sorry - thank you for the clarification - VBScripting. I have edited the tags.